# Formatting output for matrices in Python

Tags: python, decimal

I am working on some matrix problems and I'd really like the matrix outputs in the shell to look readable so I can see if the elements in it are correct.  Currently I get stuff in scientific notation like 123.4345362e-102 and entire matrices of this are really distracting.  Ideally, I'd like small enough numbers to round down to 0 and the rest to be decimals up to 4 places.

I did this before, too, but I can't remember how to do it!  It was something similar to Decimal's getcontext().prec=3, where I set it in my code at the very top and all my output looked a certain way.  It was very convenient!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Python Doc :

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 6
Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
Decimal('0.142857')
getcontext().prec = 28
Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
Decimal('0.1428571428571428571428571429')
```